# Any way to redirect a console app to the desktop?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gnome

Basically, like `conky` and other similar utilities do: they draw straight to the desktop, over the wallpaper.

Can I do it with any console app or does the app need to be coded specifically for this?

Comment: A terminal window with full transparency? That is essentially what conky is, a transparant window without decorations.

Comment: conky also does not get focus and has no icon on the dock. Also, you cannot alttab to it. It looks like something entirely different from a terminal window.